# Дефис или тире в данном случае?

Tags: тире, дефис

«АЗОВСКАЯ ШКОЛА-ГИМНАЗИЯ ИМЕНИ НИКОЛАЯ САВВЫ». Здесь уместнее дефис или же тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не фразы (словосочетания) соединяются, а лишь два слова, поэтому дефис. Тире не подходит.

Азовская не только школа, а и гимназия. Иначе можно было бы рассматривать тире.

Структура:
АЗОВСКАЯ {ШКОЛА-ГИМНАЗИЯ} ИМЕНИ НИКОЛАЯ САВВЫ.

Тире бы ставилось при такой структуре:
{АЗОВСКАЯ ШКОЛА} — {ГИМНАЗИЯ ИМЕНИ НИКОЛАЯ САВВЫ}.

Comment: Ага! Я уже думаю, если после слова, которое стоит после дефиса что-то идет дальше....то стоит ставить тире). Спасибо!